# An error while trying to add a scaffolding controller in ASP.NET MVC with Entity model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 project with ADO.NET Entity Model (Model first approach). But when I'm trying to add a new "**MVC 5 controller with views, using Entity Framework**" I get that error:

> There was an error running the selected code generator:
>
> 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'

I've created a project using [that](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/model-first-approach-in-Asp-Net-mvc-5/) tutorial.

There is one thing that is different from the tutorial: I use Windows authentication instead of SQL server authentication.

**Connection strings in the web.config:**

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication4-20170527013424.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication4-20170527013424;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="TestContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Test.csdl|res://*/Models.Test.ssdl|res://*/Models.Test.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=Test123;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I've already tried to rebuild the project and reinstall MvcScaffolding.

Any help is much appreciated!

EDIT: Apparently it's working with the ApplicationDbContext(which is default connection string), but not with the Entity Model Container.

Comment: Maybe try cleaning the project and adding the controller again? It does wonders for me.

Comment: @Tvde1 I've created two projects from zero and It's not working. BUT it's working with the ApplicationDbContext, but not working with the Entity Model Container.

Comment: you can see this great video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UNt3uWqMdMU

It helped me and it will help you too.

This is text version link of the above video:http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.in/2014/05/part-2-entity-framework-model-first_5.html

Hope it will help.thanks karthik

Comment: @KarthikElumalai Hi and thanks for the answer. Your tutorial shows how to create an ado.net model, but I have trouble adding the scaffolding controller in the asp.net mvc

Comment: My problem got solved as I cleaned up all build-problems when I noticed that the project could not even be built.